# Using Web Api 2 as Self Console Host in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to build a self Host of a Web Api 2 Webservice.
I am using the .Net Core 1.0 Framework for my Console App and also for the Web Api 2 Project.

Since there was a name change for the packages and Owin is deprecated, I am not able to rebuild the given samples in the official GitHub repository of ASPnet:

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/samples/SampleStartups/StartupHelloWorld.cs
(I tried with this one)

I looked in the project.json file which packages they are using but since I can´t find the AspNetCore.Hosting package only a package named AspNet.Hosting but i isn´t working with both packages.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*"
},
```

Resharper says something like :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebHostBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WebApiConsoleHost.DNX 4.5.1, WebApiConsoleHost.DNX Core 5.0

Just to be complete, I used the whole Main Function Body of the given sample in the Link:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseDefaultConfiguration(args)
        .UseStartup<StartupHelloWorld>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Do someone know where the WebHostBuilder class is defined ? Resharper suggests that it is in AspNet.Hosting, but after adding the using it is still not found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read the latest [docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html). It is working for me.